# How to create a thread and parse a parameter in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have an method `Process(Progressbar)` in class **Blacklist**

i tried to use this :

`Thread thread = new Thread(() => Blacklist.Process(pgImportProcess));`

it occurs an error

**C# 3.0 language Feature**

`So how can i create a thread and parse progressbar as a parameter?`

**Thank in advance**

Comment: Thread doesn't have a constructor taking a delegate, you have to pass in a ThreadStart or ParameterizedThreadStart like: Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Blacklist.Process(pgImportProcess));

Comment: @Polity : i tried as you mentioned , it alerts an error **C# 3.0 language Feature** (Note : i'm in C# 2.0 ) VS2005

Comment: because you're using lambda expressions which are njot available in C# 2.0 try: Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate{ Blacklist.Process(pgImportProcess); }));

Comment: @Polity : Thank you ! your code is working well for me , no error occur , but Can you tell me how to start ,and stop this thread?

Comment: thread.Start() and wait untill it finishes. Else, create a mechanism to stop this thread like a boolean indicating to run or not. You can forcefully abort this thread by calling thread.Abort()

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
void Invoker(){
    ParameterizedThreadStart pts = Start;
    Thread thread = new Thread(pts);
    thread.Start(new object());
}
public void Start(object o)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: llchev : No , i haven't tried it but it's not gonna work for me... , i'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can't access a UI object from a different thread than it was created on.  Every `Control` has an `Invoke` method that will execute a delegate on the UI thread.  For example if you need to update your progress bars progress:</strike>

progressBar.Invoke(new Action() { () => progressBar.Value = updateValue; });

So you just need to use the [Thread constructor that takes a ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx) delegate.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(StartProcess);
thread.Start(pgImportProcess);

...

private static void StartProcess(object progressBar) {
    Blacklist.Process((ProgressBar)progressBar);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the value of progressbar , but it's a parsing argument into thread as a Progressbar Control...

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a class to passing your parameter like

```
public class Sample
{
    object _value;

    public Sample(object value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        // dosomething
        // Invoke the Process(value)  
    }
}
```

And then

```
Sample p = new Sample("your parameter : Progressbar");
new Thread(new ThreadStart(p.Do)).Start();
```